# Recorrer un StringGrid y TDBGrid

Tags: delphi, dataset

Estimados tengo un problema, soy nuevo en delphi y quiero recorrer un StirngGrid tambien un TDBGrid, quisiera alguna sugerencia.
Estoy desarrollando una aplicación cliente - servidor  (DataSnap), pero no estoy podiendo reccorer el STringGrid, quiero desarrollar mi propio menu para recorrer el Grid.
Hace ya dos dias que estoy trabado en esto.

Editado..

Ahora tengo este problema..

```
    procedure TForm5.SpeedButton3Click(Sender: TObject);
var I : integer;
var J : integer;
var Str : String;
var client : TTServerMethodsClient;
begin
client :=   TTServerMethodsClient.Create(SQLConProductosGrid.DBXConnection);

 // Recorrido por las filas
  for I := 0 to (StringGridBindSourceDB1.RowCount - 1) do begin

    // Recorrido por las columnas
    for J := 0 to (StringGridBindSourceDB1.ColCount - 1) do begin

      // Acceso a cada celda
      Str := StringGridBindSourceDB1.Cells[J,I];
      showMessage('Acceso a la celda :'+Str);
    end;
  end;



end;
procedure TForm5.StringGridBindSourceDB1SelectCell(Sender: TObject; ACol,
  ARow: Integer; var CanSelect: Boolean);
begin
showMessage('Acceso a la celda');
BindSourceDB1.DataSet.Open;
BindSourceDB1.DataSet.DisableControls;
 BindSourceDB1.DataSet.Edit;
 BindSourceDB1.DataSet.Post;
 BindSourceDB1.DataSet.EnableControls;
end;
```

Cuando quiero acceder a la celda en el TStrinGrid me dice este error:

```
Cannot Modify a Real-Only DataSet
```

Answer (score 2):

Los `TDBGrid` son componentes que están "ligados" a una fuente de datos, así que lo normal en ese caso es recorrer la fuente de datos, no el componente. Ya sea una `TTable`, `TQuery` o cualquiera de los compoenentes derivados de `TDataset` que sería el origen a todos ellos.
Un ejemplo sencillo podría ser este:

```
var
  ds:TDataset;
begin
  // Asocia la variable
  ds := DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet;
  // Ir al inicio
  ds.First;
  // recorrer el Dataset asociado a un TDBGrid
  while (not ds.Eof) do begin
    // ...
    str := ds.FieldByName('Nombre').AsString;
    // ...
    ds.Next;
  end;
```

El caso del `TStringGrid` es diferente, porque es el propio componente el que almacena los datos, así que en este caso, sí que debes recorrer las filas y columnas para obtenerlos. Puedes revisar en la ayuda las propiedades:

- **Rows**: Acceso a las filas
- **Cols**: Acceso a las columnas
- **Cells**: Acceso a las celdas

([Listado de propiedades del TStringGrid](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Vcl.Grids.TStringGrid_Properties))

- **RowCount** y **ColCount**: Que te devuelves el número de filas y columnas definidas.

Un ejemplo sencillo de acceder a las celdas de un TStringGrid sería este:

```
  // Recorrido por las filas
  for I := 0 to (StringGrid1.RowCount - 1) do begin
    // Recorrido por las columnas
    for J := 0 to (StringGrid1.ColCount - 1) do begin
      // Acceso a cada celda
      Str := StringGrid1.Cells[J, I];
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: Gracias @german por tu comentario...me ayudo mucho.Ahora quiero editar una fila del TStringGrid, usando TStringGrid .DataSet.Edit; pero me dice esto :`Cannot Modify a Real-Only DataSet`. La verdad...no estoy encontrando la solución en Internet. Agradezco tu ayuda...

Comment: Editada mi pregunta..

Comment: @Nahuel ya Germán respondió tu pregunta original. Si quieres editar el data set, suena a una nueva pregunta. Recuerda que puedes poner como aceptada la respuesta si te ha sido de utilidad. Un saludo.